# HadoopFS (HDFS) as distributive file storage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm consider to use HDFS as horizontal scaling file storage system for our client video hosting service. My main concern that HDFS wasn't developed for this needs this is more "an open source system currently being used in situations where massive amounts of data need to be processed". 
We don't want to process data just store them, create on a base of HDFS something like small internal Amazon S3 analog.

Probably important moment is that stored file size will be quite git from 100Mb to 10Gb.

Did anyone use HDFS in such purposes?

Comment: HDFS has SPOF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_Distributed_File_System
It's fixed in latest development (alpha/beta).
Have you elaborated something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an S3 equivalient then it should already provide a distributed, mountable file-system no? Perhaps you can check out OpenStack at http://openstack.org/projects/storage/.

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage would be the lack of POSIX semantics. You can't mount the drive, and you need special APIs to read and write from it. The [Java API](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/package-summary.html) is the main one. There is a project called [libhdfs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/libhdfs.html) that makes a C API over JNI, but I've never used it. [Thriftfs](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-APIs) is another option.

I'm also not sure about the read performance compared to other alternatives. Maybe someone else knows. Have you checked out other [distributed filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_parallel_fault-tolerant_file_systems) like [Lustre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28file_system%29)?

Comment: You can actually mount the filesystem using FUSE, but it's pretty limited.

Comment: Tim, java api isn't so bad in my case, as long we are java developers, main question in overall system stability. I did check other systems from wiki page you've sent, but it first requirement - it should be open source and support big files. Many of them like MogileFS is designed to work with relatively small size files like images and so on. I didn't consider Luster yet, will do, thanks.

Comment: Stability is one of the main things of HDFS. Since it automatically replicates data, you don't have to worry about your data nodes losing data. However, currently the namenode is still a SPOF (there are HDFS patches that give you a fail over node, but they don't seem to be in mainstream Hadoop distros). Throughput is pretty good, since blocks can be streamed from all the nodes that have a replica (blocksizes often 64 or 128 MB), so you get parallel reads.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider MongoDB for this. They have GridFS which will allow you to use it as  a storage. You can then horizontally scale your storage through shards and provide fault tolerance with replication.

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/